# Runtime exception when creating an SQLite Table

Tags: android, sqlite

I am creating an android app, and using a database with it. One of the tables I am using with it is a semester table, which is created using the following statement:

```
final String createSemesterTable = 
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" + semesterTable + 
"( " + _id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + 
semesterName + " TEXT," +
isCurrent + " INTEGER," +
GPA + " REAL" + ");";
```

simple version:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Semesters(
_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
semester_name TEXT,
is_current TEXT
GPA REAL);
```

In my main activity, I try to create a Cursor Adapter that links to a list view, using the data from the database to fill the items.

Here is part of my onCreate(..) method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    dbase = new DBHelper(getBaseContext());
    sqldbase = dbase.getWritableDatabase();

    ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.semesterList);
    String columns[] = {DBHelper._id, DBHelper.semesterName, DBHelper.isCurrent, DBHelper.GPA};
    String from[] = {DBHelper.semesterName, DBHelper.GPA};
    int to[] = {R.id.semesterName, R.id.semesterGPA};

            Cursor cursor = sqldbase.query(DBHelper.semesterTable, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

    adap = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),R.layout.semester_list_view,cursor, columns, to); 

    list.setAdapter(adap);  

    }
```

When I compile/run, I get the following message, however:

```
07-06 20:34:25.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2825): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: _id (code 1): ,
while compiling: SELECT _id,     Semester_Name, Is_Current, GPA FROM Semesters
```

I don't see what is wrong, because I am using a _id column (which is actually required by SQLite). 
Also, why is _id column required (by that name)? If I have multiple tables, would I be able to set different names for their primary keys, or will _id be required for each?

Thanks.

Comment: How about adding a space after "EXISTS"? Like `"... EXISTS " + semesterTable ...`

Comment: ya i figured that out ho..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Logcat, I think you have to delete your database (may be by uninstalling your app) and then try running the app. This will recreate your database. One possibility is that you have the table already created and a `select` somewhere is failing because the `_id` column has never been created.

Comment: Hell yes! that worked! I think I might add DROP TABLE statements in my onDestroy() methods for now. thanks.